# JButton sub-class is initialized to top-left corner of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a matrix of buttons that are a subclass of JButton all in a GridLayout in a JPanel in a JFrame. I originally used a null layout and setBounds on each button but changed to a GridLayout after reading a few posts suggesting null layouts can cause issues (left commented out null layout relevant code in code pasted below). This issue occurs on both layouts. When using a standard JButton instead of my sub-class the issue doesn't occur. Please let me know other info I can provide that I might've left out. I'm just learning Swing so I'm sure I'm probably missing something obvious but I'm lost after Googling / searching YouTube for solutions. Thanks!

[image: When initially run:]
[image: Buttons appear on mouseover]

JFrame class:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class swingUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new swingUI();
    }

    public swingUI(){

        this.setSize(400,400);

        //this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();

        int xPos = (dim.width / 2) - (this.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (dim.height / 2) - (this.getHeight() / 2);

        this.setLocation(xPos, yPos);

        this.setResizable(true);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setTitle("My Frame");

        this.setLayout(null);

        this.addKeypadUI(6,4);
        //this.addDisplay();

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addKeypadUI(int rows, int cols){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel.setBounds(0,0,200,300);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(rows, cols);
        panel.setLayout(gridLayout);
        for (int c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < cols; r++) {

                KeypadButton button = new KeypadButton(r,c);
                button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                //button.setBounds(25 * r + 10, 25 * c + 10, 20, 20);
                button.setName(String.format("btn_%d_%d",r,c));
                button.addActionListener(this);
                panel.add(button);
            }
        }

        this.add(panel);
    }

//    private void addDisplay(){
//        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
//        jLabel.setText("Hello?");
//        jLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
//        jLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
//        jLabel.setBounds(250,20,110,110);
//        this.add(jLabel);
//
//    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        KeypadButton o = (KeypadButton) e.getSource();
        String name = o.getName();
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(String.format("x: %d",o.getX()));
        System.out.println(String.format("y: %d",o.getY()));
    }
}
```

Button Sub-Class:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class KeypadButton extends JButton {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    KeypadButton(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `javax.swing.JComponent` has a `getX()` method and a `getY()` method. `JButton` is a subclass of `JComponent` and so inherits those methods. Hence your `KeypadButton` class is **overriding** those methods and returning incorrect values. You want `x` to be the row of the button in the grid and the `y` to be the column so just change the names of the methods, even something like:

```java
public int get_X() {
    return this.x;
}

public int get_Y() {
    return this.y;
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! But why does the button jump to the correct location on mouseover?